# Holding one's head up high

Tags: phrase-request

How shall one say I would so something against you so that you couldn't hold your head up out of embarrassment [meaning that I will disgrace you.]
Does my self-made sentence below sound natural to indicate this message or a native speaker would not say it in that way:

> - I will do something to make you not able of **holding your head up high** in front of the public.

I would appreciate it if it doesn't sound idiomatic and natural, someone could recommend me a close idiom especially in AmE.

Comment: Did you see this [LINK](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117019/a-phrase-for-ashamed) from yesterday? It might help. If you have further questions, I'll be happy to try answering.

Comment: @WillowRex no I had not seen it up to know. But what I'm looking for is exactly opposite to it. To make someone feel shy so that they couldn't take their head up.

Comment: Do you mean (I truly do not understand) that you want to make the person feel discomfort? To be uncomfortable or make them feel humiliation or fear? I don't mean 'you' specifically, I mean you want idioms or words that express that?

Comment: @WillowRex yes. I'm looking for an idiom which can explain the situation in which one can humiliate someone else in the way they could not take their heads up ought of embarrassment. :)

Comment: I suggested *bully*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the meaning of that sentence, but it doesn't sound natural at all. Western socities aren't "shame based" and so they don't have as many natural idioms for this kind of thing, try these close alternatives.

> I will publicly humiliate you

or

> I will turn you into a social outcast.

or

> I will ruin your reputation

more dramatic

> When I'm done with you, you won't be welcome in polite society

or even

> I'll make you into a pariah

Answer (score 0):

Would bully fit your question, or any other other words in the definition?

> bully
>
> noun
>   1. a person who uses strength or power to harm or intimidate those who are weaker. synonyms:  persecutor, oppressor, tyrant, tormentor,
>   intimidator;
>
> verb
>   1. use superior strength or influence to intimidate (someone), typically to force him or her to do what one wants. "a local man was
>   bullied into helping them"

synonyms:

> persecute, oppress, tyrannize,
>   browbeat, harass, torment, intimidate, strong-arm, dominate; informal:
>   push around, bullyrag "the others bully him" coerce, pressure,
>   pressurize, press, push; force, compel; badger, goad, prod, browbeat,
>   intimidate, dragoon, strong-arm; informal: bulldoze, railroad, lean on
>   "she was bullied into helping"

Google Dictionary

> I used intimidation to get my way with her.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound idiomatic.  Usually I hear "hold your head high" as positive, but I can imagine some alternates:

> I will make you hang your head in shame.

or close to what you said "make you not able of" but a bit more idiomatic:

> What I say will make it so you cannot hold your head high in public.

Above is a bit more concise so more common (in my experience).  I would also consider it ok to say:

> What I say will make you not able to hold your head high in public.